# Using our Apple account to distribute apps archived by other team

Tags: ios

The situation is that company A using its Apple Account archived a package for distribution and send it to company B which is responsible for distribution.The two company both use their own Apple Account doing those operations.Can this is possible under current rules of Apple?If not, would mind give me some advice on how to deal with this problem?Thanks in advance!

Edit1: By using Export and Import Developer Profile.
When I use the method which is @Russian 's suggestion, I failed.The snapshot is below.

[image]

Edit2: Without account password, I can't sign in.There will be an 
error during archiving if I do not sign in the account.

[image]

Edit3: Without account login, I can not configure the Development Team[image]

Comment: Sos help me, help me!

Comment: @Russian Please see the snapshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done if company B exports its developer profile and provides company A with it, so that company A will import that developer profile and use it when generating an archive. Having generating an archive, company A sends that archive to company B, which then uploads it to the AppStore with Application Loader.

Comment: Thanks! When company A imports that developer profile, Does it have the right to create or remove any certificates under this Account?

Comment: Nope. Exporting developer profile for other company to use is not the same as giving access to Apple Developer/iTunes Connect account, so company A is going to be very limited in what they can do with that profile. That basically amounts to the ability to sign archives and nothing else.

Comment: When I use the developer profile, there prompt an alert to ask me to input the password of the developer account!

Comment: My boss was very angry with my report which is describing the method you told me,  because it does not work and still need the account's password to log in.What should I do now? How can I make it up?

Comment: I hope my operation is error and you can give me a detailed instruction on how to do archiving by exporting and importing Developer Profile.Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: @wanchen what company do you represent? A or B? do you need to generate an archive or distribute already generated archive?

Comment: Dear Russian, I am a staff of company A.I have to generate an archive for company B who is responsible to distribution.My boss do not want to give B our source code, so he ask me to think out a method to solve this problem.

Comment: Do you have B's developer profile at your disposal? You need to ask them to export their dev account and send it to you, so that you could import it on your machine. After you've imported their profile, you just generate an archive as you would normally do by first configuring the appropriate signing settings (Provisioning Profile, Team and Certificate) and then kicking off the archiving process (by selecting Product -> Archive from the menu) without paying any attention to Xcode asking you for password.

Comment: I have several developer accounts imported which I don’t have passwords for, and it doesn’t prevent me from being able to generate archives (although password prompts Xcode keeps popping at me are quite annoying)

Comment: Yes I do.I have B's dev profile and have imported it, then I start to generate an archive, but I have to input the account's password of the dev profile.However, B is not willing to afford us their password!

Comment: As I specified above, you don't need their password to be able to generate an archive.

Comment: Would you mind give some snapshots for me to follow?my email is wanchenxie@163.com. You are really a kind person, thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Without login an account, I do not know how to do an appropriate signing settings.Really hope you can give me a hand!Thanks again!